# Super Search Pagination deleting parts of URL

Tags: solspace, pagination, supersearch

I am trying to pass an entry ID which is wrapped in the super search results tag into a channel loop, and using the channel loop pagination to brow through the pages.

```
{embed="{prv_template_group}/_shop-list" 
    entry_id="{exp:super_search:results}{entry_id}|{/exp:super_search:results}"
    limit="{prv_limit}"
}   



{paginate}      
    <div class="pagination">
        <span>
          {pagination_links}
        </span>
    </div>
{/paginate}
```

When I first submit the super search, it gives me the correct url:

.../index.php/shop/results/search&category=boy&&Footwear&&"Ickle+Shooz"/

But when I click any of the pagination links, it gives me this:

.../index.php/shop/results/search&category=boy&&Footwear&&

---

Another problem, it also does not seem to recognise + symbols:

.../index.php/shop/results/search&category=default+boy/

and when you click onto a pagination link:

.../index.php/shop/results/search&category=default%20boy/P9

---

Has anyone ever come across this problem before and know how to fix it?

Running short of ideas!!

Comment: So the {exp:channel:entries} is inside the embed? Why go through all this trouble? Why not use {exp:super_search:results} on its own, no embeds, no {exp:channel:entries}? {exp:super_search:results} can be used as a near replacement of {exp:channel:entries}. It should have all the tools you need to create paginated results. Unless there's a specific need.